# How to pass null to javascript from python using jinja

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-visualization, jinja2

I was doing it something like this in google app engine:

```
self.render('hello.html', value=null)
```

But obviously since python doesn't understand null it thinks it's an undefined variable and gives an error.

If I send it as a string (value="null") then javascript doesn't know that I mean null and not a string "null".

So what's the way to get around this?

And if it's any bit pertinent, I'm trying to pass the value null to a google scatter chart in javascript.

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of your template?

Comment: @Michael just tried but didn't work. Javascript doesn't understand None and thinks it's an undefined variable!

Comment: @skreft there's nothing special about my template. I'm just basically trying to pass an array to google visualization chart API in javascript from my python code using jinja 2.
The array should be of the form: plotdata = [0.1, null, null, 0.5]. But python is refusing to just send null because it thinks it's a variable i'm not defining.

Comment: @afroze On a more basic note, why are you passing `null` in the first place? Can't you just initialize the value to `null` in your javascript if value is not set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming your are doing something like:

```
self.render('hello.html', value=[0.1, None, None, 0.5])
```

and having the template engine convert that to a string, so you end up with:

```
 [0.1, None, None, 0.5]
```

If so, you should have python convert it to javascript before passing to jinja:

```
import json
self.render('hello.html', value=json.dumps([0.1, None, None, 0.5]))
```

That'll give you:

```
[0.1, null, null, 0.5]
```

which is what I think you are after.

A even better solution would be to add a [custom filter to jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) to handle javascript escaping.  That would look something like:

```
import json
def jsonfilter(value):
    return json.dumps(value)

environment.filters['json'] = jsonfilter
```

Then in your template you could just do

```
{{value|json}}
```

Comment: Thanks that turned out very well!

Comment: This works for me too - thanks.  And it seems like the most "correct" way.

Answer (score 3):

assuming your template looks something like:

```
plotdata = [0.1, {{value}}, null, 0.5]
```

(depending on the template engine you are using), then:

```
self.render('hello.html', { "value": "null" })
```

should result in the rendered template producing:

```
plotdata = [0.1, null, null, 0.5]
```

If this is not working, please tell us the template engine you are using, the values you've tried sending, and the exact result of rendering..